# Using dateparser to get a range of dates

Tags: python, dateparser

I was having a problem with `dateparser` when it is given a string such as `"Dec. 3-4"`. I have an array of dates (without year) but I have no idea how I would split up that date to make it print out `"12/3"` and `"12/4"`.

My current output is `"12/3"` and then it gives me an error `NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime'`. Here is the `for` loop I am using to print out the dates.

```
for i in range(len(data_table)):
    date = dateparser.parse(data_table[i][0])
    date_output.insert(i, date.strftime("%m/%d/2020"))
    txt_two = "{:25}{}".format(date_output[i], data_table[i][1])
    print(txt_two)
```

Comment: Can you give an example value for `data_table`?

Comment: Oh sure! Let's say the table is filled with values:
Aug. 3
Aug. 26
Sept. 7
Oct. 2
Nov. 25-27
Dec. 2
Dec. 3-4
Dec. 28

Comment: Can you please give me an example of the data_table result?

Comment: So is it something like `[("Aug. 3",), ("Aug. 26",), ("Nov. 25-27",),]` etc?

Comment: @BradleyFelix If the dates are all in the same format there's not much point in using dateparser - esp. as it can't handle date-ranges. You might as well use a regular expression.

Comment: @Samwise yeah, like that

Answer (score 1):

For ranges I came up with something like this:

```
def extract_dates(date_string):
  matcher = matcher = re.compile('\\d+-\\d+')
  match = matcher.search(date_string)
  if match:
    start, end = match.group(0).split('-')
    prefix = date_string[:5]
    return [prefix + str(i) for i in range(start, end + 1)]
  else:
    return [date_string]
```